# Windows Phone 7 network traffic tracking - how?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient, tracking

I would need to track how much many bytes are sent and received by my application per session. Is there some API for this provided by the OS? Or is the only way to somehow manually track this every time I send/receive something with WebClient instance?

Comment: If you're doing the sending and receiving, couldn't you just use the `Length` property on the byte stream you're receiving/sending?

Comment: Well, I do not have direct control to all components of the app that send/receive. Also, before implementing custom counters, I would like to know if there is a convinient application wide solution to this available (like and service provided by the OS etc)

Comment: I don't believe there is any API to monitor traffic. Closest I can think of is to read the Length property but, like you say, that won't help when using other components you don't control.

Answer (score 1):

As keyboardP mentions. This is currently not supported by the API.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in but you could build a decorator `IWebRequestCreate` decorator implementation that tracks the bandwidth being used.